# If $Z$ is the center of the group $G$ and $G/Z$ is abelian, prove that $G$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

That if $G/Z$ is cyclic, $G$ is abelian is provable. 
I just wanted to see if the statement holds given the weaker assumption that $G/Z$ is abelian instead of being cyclic(cyclic is stronger because cyclic anyway implies abelian).
So far I could do the following:

Since $G/Z$ is abelian,

$$Za Zb=Zb Za$$ for some $a,b \in G.$
Since $Z$ is a normal subgroup as well so left cosets are same as right cosets.
$$\therefore ZZab=ZZba$$
Thus we have finally,
$$Zab=Zba \implies ab(ba)^{-1} \in Z.$$ How do I proceed from here to prove that $ab=ba$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't work. (I mean, your proposed idea of replacing "$G/Z$ cyclic" with "$G/Z$ abelian." Being Abelian is not sufficient.)

Consider the dihedral group of order $8$ and its center.

Comment: So you mean to say that it is necessary for G/Z to be cyclic for G to be abelian?

Comment: @MadhurPanwar I'm saying that $G/Z$ being Abelian is *not sufficient* to prove $G$ is abelian. I would agree that $G/Z$ being cyclic *is sufficient* to show $G$ is abelian. I did not say "it is necessary" to be cyclic.

Comment: That helped. Thanks. I got your argument.

Comment: Isn't it necessary? $G$ abelian implies $G/Z$ is trivial (hence cyclic).

Comment: @DavidHill I didn't untangle it down to that level, but yes, I suppose it is literally true. I was trying to tell Madhur what I meant to emphasize (which was not this fact.)